# Laravel Eloquent with() selecting specific column doesn't return results

Tags: laravel

Say I have 2 models, Category and POI where 1 Category can have many POIs.

```
$categoryDetails = Category::with([
    'pois' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('is_poi_enabled', true);
    },
])->findOrFail($id);
```

The above query returns results from the specific Category as well as its POIs.

However, with the query below:

```
$query->select('id', 'name')->where('is_poi_enabled', true);
```

The POIs become empty in the collection.

Any idea why this is happening? When added a select clause to the Eloquent ORM?

Comment: Which is the foreign key user for `pois` ? Select that foreign key too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While doing a select it's required to fetch the Relationship local or Primary key. 
For an example POIs table contains category_id then it's required to select it 
Try this:

```
$categoryDetails = Category::with([
    'pois' => function ($query) {
        $query->select(['id', 'category_id', 'is_poi_enabled'])
       ->where('is_poi_enabled', true);
    },
])->findOrFail($id);
```

Good luck!

Comment: But why is it not required when it's a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: It depends if you are using pivot table it's required if your connecting table with primary or local keys it's required.